# AWS Rekognition detect and save face from image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

As per AWS Rekognition document, there are some methods available which I can use to detect the face in image and it returns me response in below format-

```
         "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.36868685483932495,
            "Height": 0.5219123363494873,
            "Left": 0.6035353541374207,
            "Top": 0.4302788972854614
        },
        "Confidence": 99.55957794189453
```

Is there any way I can use this response and crop original image to capture only face.

Example- Capture photo from passport/DL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The `BoundingBox` is telling you where the face is within the image, with figures as a percentage.

So, the face width occupies 36% of the image and starts 60% from the left.

The face height occupies 52% of the image, starting 43% from the top.

Therefore, the face is on the lower right side.

You can **multiply these figures by the actual image width and height**. Let's say that the image is 2000 pixels wide and 1000 pixels tall, the face would be at:

```
Top-left corner = (2000 x .6, 1000 x .43) = (1200,430)
Bottom-right corner = (2000 x (.60 + .37), 1000 x (.43 + .52)) = (1940,950)
```

You can use these co-ordinates with a graphics library to **extract the face from the *original* image file** (but not from Rekognition, which does not store the original image).